# How to create a script to launch several emulated ROM inside a folder

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I would like to create a script to run simultaneously all the N64 Roms that I put inside a folder, reading the names from a text file.

Since now I did a script like this:

```
cat ./listN64_full.txt | while read line; do
    mupen64plus $line 
    echo "|"
done
```

The problem is that when the first emulated ROM is launched the script stops and I have to close the active window to run the second one.

How should I edit that script to load all them together?
The pipe seems doesn't work...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Minimal modification to your script

```
#!/bin/bash
cat ./listN64_full.txt | while read -r line; do
  mupen64plus "$line" & 
  sleep 1   # Better to give a second or 2 to create the window 
  echo "|"  # It's here because so it was... 
done
```

When you execute a script is like if you write it line by line.
It's more safe to use `read -r line` instead of `read line`.

To execute a command in background you have to put the **`&`** at the end of the command line.